# Download PDF From mysql using node.js and ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, ejs

I am trying to write a page that can upload PDF to MySQL database and then download it again at a later stage. The Database I have set as a BLOB and at this stage is able to upload PDF to the database with the code below. I am just not sure how to download the file from the database back to pdf format using ejs and node.js. IS there someone that has done this or knows how to do this?

HTML

```
//EJS - HTML side using bodyParser to return value to my .js server

<input type="file" name="file" value="" class="form-control"/><br></p>
```

NODE JS

```
//.js server side
app.post('/addfile', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body);
connection.query("INSERT INTO data (file) VALUES ('"+req.body.file+"')", function (err, result){
console.log(result);
res.redirect(URL);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file from MySQL using a normal SELECT query.

After you have the file, you can send the file by invoking [`res.send`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send) method provided by Express with relevant headers.

It should look something like:

```
var fileData = new Buffer(blob);
res.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
  'Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.pdf',
  'Content-Length': fileData.length
});
res.write(fileData);
res.end();
```

You may want to set relevant header l